# Middle clicking an icon on the plank dock no longer opens a new window

Tags: plank

For many years, performing a middle click on a dock item (e.g. Terminal, Files), will open a new instance of the application e.g. if you want two terminal windows open to view side by side.

Recently, this is no longer working and a pinwheel spins for a while and then no action occurs. 
The only workaround so far is to right click on the icon and choose "New Window"

How can I restore this necessary functionality?

Comment: This is likely an issue with the specific apps (e.g. Terminal, Files) rather than the dock as I can't see any significant changes there that would the cause of this. It may be worth opening an issue on the relevant GitHub pages.

Comment: Middle mouse click works for me, but I compiled Plank from the source.

Comment: Which application exhibit this behaviour? I tried Firefox and a new window shows up. Terminal and Files instead are just focused and no new window is created. So as suggested by @DavidHewitt it seems an application related issue.

Comment: terminal and files in particular ones i've noticed. these applications are supplied by elementary, suggesting a common config/issue, and only recently started exhibiting this behaviour in recent months

Answer (score -1):

```
cd && cd Downloads
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/plank/0.11.89-1/plank_0.11.89.orig.tar.xz
tar xf plank_0.11.89.orig.tar.xz
cd plank-0.11.89
 ./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo apt install --reinstall plank libplank*
```

Additionally to enable zoom in Plank:

Two files need to be edited before you can get the zoom effect, copy/paste.

```
sudo nano /usr/local/share/plank/themes/Default/dock.theme
```

Add the following in the end of the file;

```
ZoomEnabled=true
ZoomPercent=150
```

Save: [ctrl]+[o] and Exit: [ctrl]+[x]

The last file to edit is the schema file of Plank.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/net.launchpad.plank.gschema.xml
```

Look for (near the end of the file).

false

Change false to true

Save: [ctrl]+[o] and Exit: [ctrl]+[x]

Last thing.

```
killall plank&& plank&
plank --preferences
```

Now enable Zoom effect in preferences.

Comment: this answer doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question